# basemap Unknown property latlon

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, keyword, scatter, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot with Basemap, but for me the `latlon` keyword does not work. Here is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def test():
    fig = plt.figure
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180,
    llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlon=180,urcrnrlat=90,projection='mill') 
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.65, color='0.3')
    x = 30.
    y = 50.
    m.scatter(x, y, s=50, color='k', latlon=True)   
    plt.show()
```

After running I got the error: `Unknown property latlon`. Any idea about that, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. Your code works fine for me using Python 2.7.3 and iPython 1.1.0. Are you perhaps using an old version of Basemap that doesn't support the `latlon` kwarg?

Comment: @SpencerHill Thank you, I am using Python 2.7.3 and iPython 0.12.1. I do not know how to check for version of Basemap, but I did a quick check with "Basemap ?" in Ipython and saw that there is no latlon in the list of keywords, so probably my version is obsolete. Can you please tell me how to check for Basemap version? I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I just tried it on another machine with iPython 0.13.1 and it worked. Maybe just try updating to the latest version of Basemap.

Comment: @SpencerHill Thank you, my Basemap and Ipython have just been updated to 1.0.7 and 1.2.0, respectively. It took so long time because I don't have root password for the institute's computer. Now everything works well